# java.io.IOException: Unable to allocate socket for blob server in specified port range: 0

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm porting [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) to Android. Even in standalone mode, a `ServerSocket` must be created. This is how `BlobServer.java` creates a `ServerSocket`:

```
    ServerSocket socketAttempt = NetUtils.createSocketFromPorts(ports, new NetUtils.SocketFactory() {
        @Override
        public ServerSocket createSocket(int port) throws IOException {
            return new ServerSocket(port, finalBacklog);
        }
    });

    if(socketAttempt == null) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to allocate socket for blob server in specified port range: "+serverPortRange);
    } else {
        this.serverSocket = socketAttempt;
    }
```

By default, `port` value is `0`, so the port used is decided by the OS. This is the `ServerSocket` constructor called:

```
public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress localAddress) throws IOException {
        checkListen(port);
        this.impl = factory != null ? factory.createSocketImpl()
                : new PlainServerSocketImpl();
        InetAddress addr = (localAddress == null) ? Inet6Address.ANY : localAddress;

        synchronized (this) {
            impl.create(true); //SOMETHING GOES WRONG!
            try {
                impl.bind(addr, port);
                readBackBindState();
                impl.listen(backlog > 0 ? backlog : DEFAULT_BACKLOG);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                close();
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Following the Debugger, the `addr` value is `://` (I don't know if this is correct or not) and `port` is `0` (correct), BUT the `ServerSocket` constructor execution is interrupted when `impl.create(true)` is executed (returning `null`) and this exception is thrown in `BlobServer.java` (after having checked that the returned `ServerSocket` is null):

`java.io.IOException: Unable to allocate socket for blob server in specified port range: 0
...`

Why this happens? And how can I resolve it?

**UPDATE:**
Digging in the code, I've reached the following method in `PlainServerSocketImpl.java`:

```
protected void create(boolean isStreaming) throws IOException {
    super.create(isStreaming);//CANNOT GO FURTHER WITH THE DEBUGGER!
    if (isStreaming) {
        setOption(SocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I hit "next" with the debugger on `super.create()` I cannot follow anymore since it's opened the `PainSocketImpl.java` for unix systems (with `native` method callings). How can I continue to dig with the debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the addr value is :// (I don't know if this is correct or not)

It isn't, and it is almost certainly the cause of the problem. Host addresses are not URLs. It should be a dotted-quad IP address or a hostname known to your DNS.

> and port is 0 (correct), BUT the ServerSocket constructor execution is interrupted when impl.create(true) is executed (returning null) and this exception is thrown in BlobServer.java

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to allocate socket for blob server in specified port range: 0
```

Your own error message is of no interest. What would be of interest would be the *original* error message in the original `IOException`. Don't make up your own messages. It makes debugging impossible.

> (after having checked that the returned ServerSocket is null):

It isn't null. It wasn't returned. An exception was thrown instead.

Comment: I agree with you "own messages", but this message isn't mine, is Flinks's :) And btw I'll try to get the original error in the original IOException. And btw YES, the value is null (look at the first code portion of code that I updated)

Comment: THere is nothing in your last update or indeed anywhere in the JLS that indicates that a method that throws an exception can also return null. That's only possible if some undisclosed intermediate layer caught the exception and returned null. This seems to be a very poorly written piece of software, whoever is responsible. I'm also curious how a call to a two-argument constructor that calls a three-argument constructor with a third parameter of `null` can end up in the three-argument constructor with a non-null value for that argument.